# Hacer un gráfico utilizando Highcharts

Tags: python, web2py, highcharts

Disculpen, es la primera vez que estoy trabando con Highcharts con web2py.

Tengo esta tabla:

```
db.define_table('registros_documentos',
                Field('numero_expediente', 'string'),
                Field('fecha_registro', 'date'),
                Field('usuario', 'reference usuarios'),
                format='%(numero_expediente)s')
```

Donde registra los documentos ingresados por fecha y por usuario y tengo que hacer un gráfico que me muestre la fecha y la cantidad de expedientes por usuario Hasta aquí llegué:

```
def registro_grafico():
    datos = db(db.registros_documentos.id>0).select(
        db.registros_documentos.numero_expediente,
        db.registros_documentos.fecha_registro,
        db.registros_documentos.usuario,
        left=(
            db.usuarios.on(db.usuarios.id==db.registros_documentos.usuario),
        )
    )
    return datos

options = {}
    dias = 30
    if len(datos) == 0:
    for data in datos:
        options['name'] = data['registros_documentos.usuario']
        options['numero_expediente'] = data['registros_documentos.numero_expediente']
        dias = data['registros_documentos.fecha_registro']
    if dias is None or dias == '':
        dias = 30
    query = False
    for valor in options['name']:
        query |= (db.usuarios.id==valor )
    aux_datos = db(query).select(
        db.registros_documentos.usuario,
        db.registros_documentos.numero_expediente,
        left=db.usuarios.on(db.usuarios.id==db.registros_documentos.usuario),
    )
```

Pero después de eso no me esta funcionando, quisiera hacer un grafico que me muestre las fechas abajo los usuarios separados por cantidad de documentos que registren, ¿cómo paso los datos a JSON para usarlo o llamarlo en el template HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, el resultado de un `select` en web2py es un iterable de regitros, por lo tanto tendrías que armar manualmente los datos que necesitas para el gráfico (no has mencionado que tipo de gráfico vas a usar), luego convertir los datos a JSON y pasarlos a tu template.

### Inicio

Por lo que requieres, se me ocurre que podrías usar un [Bar Chart](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/bar-chart), lo que necesitarías inicialmente es un diccionario con los parámetros del gráfico que le vas a pasar a Highcharts en tu template.

La idea es que finalmente tengas algo como esto en tu código Python:

```
parametros = {
    'chart': {
        'type': 'bar'
    },
    'title': {
        'text': 'Expedientes de Usuario por Fecha',
    },
    'credits': {
        'enabled': False
    },
    'xAxis': {
        'categories': ['25/03/16', '26/03/16', '27/03/16', '28/03/16']
    },
    'yAxis': {
        'title': {
            'text': 'Documentos'
        },
    },
    'tooltip': {
        'valueSuffix': ' documentos'
    },
    'legend': {
        'layout': 'vertical',
        'align': 'right',
        'verticalAlign': 'middle',
        'borderWidth': 0
    },
    'series': [
        {
            'name': 'Juan',
            'data': [2, 7, 6, 9]
        },
        {
            'name': 'Carlos',
            'data': [10, 2, 3, 25]
        }, 
        {
            'name': 'Ernesto',
            'data': [8, 10, 20, 15]
        }, 
        {
            'name': 'Alejandro',
            'data': [4, 2, 1, 3]
        }
    ]
}
```

Lo de arriba generaría en Highcharts algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No te asustes, solo he copiado los parámetros de un ejemplo cualquiera de la documentación de Highcharts y lo he adaptado a tu caso.

### Preparación

En lo que sí tienes que fijarte es en lo que vamos a necesitar para armar este gráfico. En el ejemplo puse los datos en duro, lo que tenemos que calcular son las categorías del eje X:

```
'xAxis': {
    'categories': ['25/03/16', '26/03/16', '27/03/16', '28/03/16']
}
```

Y las series para cada usuario:

```
'series': [
    {
        'name': 'Juan',
        'data': [2, 7, 6, 9]
    },
    # etc.
]
```

### Ejecución

No se exactamente cuál será finalmente el query que vas a utilizar ni qué filtros le vas a aplicar, asi que asumiré que ya tienes filtrado los resultados del query para, por ejemplo, todo el mes de Febrero del 2016.

```
import calendar
import datetime
import json

def grafico():
    year = 2016 # "ano" suena feo
    month = 2
    dias_totales = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]

    # Esto genera todos los días del mes de febrero como texto
    categorias = [datetime.date(year, month, day).strftime('%d/%m/%y') for day in range(1, dias_totales+1)]

    # Esto lo vamos a llenar más abajo 
    series = []

    # El query con los filtros que le apliques para Febrero 2016
    documentos = db(db.registros_documentos.id>0).select(...) 

    documentos_por_usuario = {}

    # Iteramos los registros para luego armar las series
    for documento in documentos:
        usuario = documento.usuario.nombre
        if documento.usuario.nombre not in documentos_por_usuario:
            # Inicializamos el usuario con 0 documentos en cada día
            documentos_por_usuario[usuario] = [0] * dias_totales
        # Aumentamos en 1 la cantidad de documentos
        documentos_por_usuario[usuario][documento.fecha_registro.day-1] += 1

    # Hay que convertir los datos al formato aceptado para las series
    for nombre, cantidades in documentos_por_usuario.items():
        series.append({
            'name': nombre, # Cesar
            'data': cantidades # [2, 0, 7, 0, ... 10, 2]
        })

    # Los parámetros del gráfico
    parametros = {
        'chart': {
            'type': 'bar'
        },
        'title': {
            'text': 'Documentos de Usuario por Fecha',
        },
        'credits': {
            'enabled': False
        },
        'xAxis': {
            'categories': categorias
        },
        'yAxis': {
            'title': {
                'text': 'Documentos'
            },
        },
        'tooltip': {
            'valueSuffix': ' documentos'
        },
        'legend': {
            'layout': 'vertical',
            'align': 'right',
            'verticalAlign': 'middle',
            'borderWidth': 0
        },
        'series': series
    }

    # Lo convertimos a JSON
    parametros = json.dumps(parametros)

    # Lo enviamos al template
    return dict(parametros=parametros)
```

Ahora, solo queda mostrar el cuadro en tu template con los parámetros que has calculado en tu controlador. Tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var parametros = JSON.parse("{{=parametros}}");
        $('#container').highcharts(parametros);
    });
</script>
```

### Fin

Algunas cosas que tienes que tener en cuenta:

- **No lo he probado** ya que no tengo web2py instalado y tampoco uso web2py hace mucho tiempo.
- Es la primera forma que se me ocurrió, con más tiempo y más calma podría salir alguna mejor forma de hacerlo.
- Estoy asumiendo que tu modelo `usuarios` tiene un campo llamado nombre, ya depende de ti como quieres que se muestre ese nombre en el gráfico.
- La función [`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) recibe el año y el mes y retorna una tupla con el número de día del primer día del mes y la cantidad de días del mes:

  ```
  print calendar.monthrange(2016, 2) # (0, 29)
  ```
- JSON no es más que una notación para representar objetos, Python viene con su propio módulo [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) al igual que JavaScript también cuenta con el módulo [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON).
- Te recomendé un Bar Chart ya que como vas a trabajar con fechas esto puede crecer mucho horizontalmnete, creo que es mejor tenerlo en forma vertical.

Bien, espero que todo esto sea entendible.