# Error cuando quiero hacer una gráfica con Highcharts

Tags: python, web2py, highcharts

Estoy trabajando con highcharts, deseo hacer una gráfica que me muestre la cantidad de documentos recibidos por cada usuario en un rango de fecha que se elija

Este es mi data:

```
db.define_table('usuarios',
                Field('nombre', 'string'),
                format='%(nombre)s'
                )


db.define_table('registro',
                Field('numero_documento', 'string'),
                Field('usuario', 'reference usuarios'),
                Field('fecha_ingreso', 'date'),
                format='%(numero_documento)s'
                )
```

Este es mi controlador:

```
def datos_fechas():

    form = SQLFORM.factory(
        Field('usuario', 'reference usuarios',requires=IS_IN_DB(db, db.usuarios, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----')),
        Field('desde', 'date'),
        Field('hasta', 'date'),
    )
    year = 2016
    month = 2
    dias_totales = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    categorias = [datetime.date(year, month, day).strftime('%d/%m/%y') for day in range(1, dias_totales+1)]
    series = []
    data = []
    if form.process().accepted:
        usuario = form.vars.usuario
        desde = form.vars.desde
        hasta = form.vars.hasta
        if desde is None or hasta is None:
            return
        data = db((db.registro.usuario==usuario) &
                  ((db.registro.fecha_ingreso>=desde) & (db.registro.fecha_ingreso<=hasta))
                  ).select(
            db.usuarios.nombre,
            db.registro.numero_documento,
            db.registro.fecha_ingreso,
            left=(
            db.usuarios.on(db.usuarios.id==db.registro.usuario),
                 )
        )
    documentos_por_usuario = {}

    for documento in data:
        usuario = documento.usuario.nombre
        if documento.usuario.nombre not in documentos_por_usuario:
            documentos_por_usuario[usuario] = [0] * dias_totales
        documentos_por_usuario[usuario][documento.fecha_registro.day-1] += 1
    for nombre, cantidades in documentos_por_usuario.items():
        series.append({
            'name': nombre,
            'data': cantidades
        })
    parametros = {
        'chart': {
            'type': 'bar'
        },
        'title': {
            'text': 'Documentos de Usuario por Fecha',
        },
        'credits': {
            'enabled': False
        },
        'xAxis': {
            'categories': categorias
        },
        'yAxis': {
            'title': {
                'text': 'Documentos'
            },
        },
        'tooltip': {
            'valueSuffix': ' documentos'
        },
        'legend': {
            'layout': 'vertical',
            'align': 'right',
            'verticalAlign': 'middle',
            'borderWidth': 0
        },
        'series': series
    }
    parametros = json.dumps(parametros)
    return dict(parametros=parametros, form=form, data=data)
```

y esta es mi vista:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<h1>Datos Fechas</h1>
{{=form}}

{{if len(data) > 0:}}
    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Usuario</th>
    <th>N° Documento</th>
    <th>Fecha de registro</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
{{
for elem in data:
=elem
pass
}}
    </tbody>
    </table>
{{pass}}

<div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var parametros = JSON.parse("{{=parametros}}");
        $('#container').highcharts(parametros);
    });
</script>
```

Finalmente el error que me da es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Desarrollo\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "D:/Desarrollo/web2py/applications/prueba/controllers/reports.py", line 99, in <module>
  File "D:\Desarrollo\web2py\gluon\globals.py", line 412, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "D:/Desarrollo/web2py/applications/prueba/controllers/reports.py", line 58, in datos_fechas
    usuario = documento.usuario.nombre
  File "D:\Desarrollo\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\objects.py", line 90, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError
```

... se que el error esta por aca "usuario = documento.usuario.nombre" pero quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal exactamente.

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes incluir el modelo `usuario` al que haces referencia en el modelo `registro`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunas cosas que corregir, como había mencionado en tu pregunta anterior [Hacer un gráfico utilizando Highcharts](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6443/hacer-un-gr%C3%A1fico-utilizando-highcharts), no usaba web2py hace algún tiempo. Debí haber verificado algunas cosas en el código.

Bueno, aquí estan mis observaciones:

- Como estás haciendo un left join (usando el parámetro `left` en el `select`) con la tabla `db.usuarios`, el resultado de cada registro se debería ver mas o menos así:

  ```
  <Row {'registro': {'numero_documento': 'doc1111', 'fecha_ingreso': datetime.date(2016, 4, 1)}, 'usuarios': {'nombre': 'Cesar'}}>
  ```

  Por lo tanto, al usar:

  ```
  >>> documento.usuario
  *** AttributeError:
  ```

  Lo correcto es usar:

  ```
  >>> documento.usuarios.nombre
  'Cesar'
  ```

  Lo mismo para la fecha de ingreso, lo correcto es:

  ```
  >>> documento.registro.fecha_ingreso
  datetime.date(2016, 4, 1)
  ```

  Finalmente, el código de la iteración de registros debería quedar así:

  ```
  documentos_por_usuario = {}
  for documento in documentos:
      usuario = documento.usuarios.nombre
      if usuario not in documentos_por_usuario:   
          documentos_por_usuario[usuario] = [0] * dias_totales
      documentos_por_usuario[usuario][documento.registro.fecha_ingreso.day-1] += 1
  ```
- Al renderizar los parámetros para Highcharts en tu template debes usar la función [XML()](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#XML) que le indica a web2py que no escape los caracteres especiales, es decir, usando `XML()` se mostrará en el template `"credits"` en vez de `&quot;credits&quot;`.

  También, como al usar `JSON.parse` en JavaScript convierte las comillas simples de Python a comillas dobles, debes usar comillas simples al renderizar.

  Quedaría así:

  ```
  var parametros = JSON.parse('{{=XML(parametros)}}');
  ```