# Cómo agrupar los elementos de una lista por usuario y con el total de veces que el usuario ha hecho un registro?

Tags: python, web2py

Esta es mi data:

```
db.define_table('usuarios',
                Field('nombre', 'string'),
                format='%(nombre)s'
                )

db.define_table('registro',
                Field('numero_documento', 'string'),
                Field('usuario', 'reference usuarios'),
                Field('fecha_ingreso', 'date'),
                format='%(numero_documento)s'
                )
```

estoy tratando de sacar el numero de veces que un usuario ha llenado un registro para ello tomo como base el campo `usuario` dentro de `registro` ; estoy pasando los datos a una lista con esta funcion:

```
def pie_chart():
    query = (db.registro.id > 0)
    data = db(query).select(
        db.usuarios.nombre,
        left=(
            db.usuarios.on(db.usuarios.id==db.registro.usuario),
            )
    )
    new_data=[]
    for row in data:
        row_date = row['usuarios.nombre']
        tmp = [row_date]
        new_data.append(tmp)
    return dict(data=new_data)
```

con la que me devuelve esta data:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estaba tratando de sumar y agrupar el numero de registros por usuario asi:

```
series = []
    cantidad_usuarios = {}
    for line in data:
        usuario = line.usuarios.nombre
        if  usuario not in cantidad_usuarios:
            cantidad_usuarios[usuario] = [0]
        cantidad_usuarios[usuario] += 1
    for nombre, cantidades in cantidad_usuarios.items():
        series.append({
            'name': nombre,
            'data': cantidades
        })
```

pero no me esta funcionando.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que al Pie Chart le pasas cantidades? Me parece que son porcentajes, verifícalo en la documentación de Highcharts

Comment: Claro, trabaja con porcentajes pero quería tener la data primero y de ahi ver la manera de sacarle el porcentaje con el total de registros que seria un len(data) salvo haya una mejor manera

Comment: Viendo la documentación al parecer aceptar cualquier valor numérico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que yo haría es algo similar la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6443/hacer-un-gr%C3%A1fico-utilizando-highcharts) que te di anteriormente, pero orientado al Pie Chart.

La idea acá es más sencilla, es simplemente contar el total de documentos por cada usuario:

```
import json    

def grafica():
    registros = db(db.registro.id > 0).select(
        db.usuarios.nombre,
        left=(
            db.usuarios.on(db.usuarios.id==db.registro.usuario),
        )
    )
    usuarios = {}
    for registro in registros:
        nombre = registro.nombre
        if nombre not in usuarios:
            usuarios[nombre] = 0
        usuarios[nombre] += 1

    # Pasarlo al formato de Highcharts
    data = []
    for nombre, total in usuarios.items():
        data.append({
            'name': nombre,
            'y': total
        })

    # Los parámetros para el Pie Chart incluyendo la data que calculamos arriba
    parametros = {
        'chart': {
            'plotBackgroundColor': None,
            'plotBorderWidth': None,
            'plotShadow': False,
            'type': 'pie'
        },
        'title': {
            'text': 'Documentos totales por Usuario'
        },
        'tooltip': {
            'pointFormat': '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:.1f}</b>'
        },
        'plotOptions': {
            'pie': {
                'allowPointSelect': True,
                'cursor': 'pointer',
                'dataLabels': {
                    'enabled': True,
                    'format': '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                }
            }
        },
        'series': [{
            'name': 'Total documentos',
            'colorByPoint': True,
            'data': data
        }]
    }
    parametros = json.dumps(parametros)
    return dict(parametros=parametros)
```

Finalmente, en tu template:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var parametros = JSON.parse('{{=XML(parametros)}}');
        $('#container').highcharts(parametros);
    });
</script>
```

El resultado sería algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se muestra el porcentaje general para cada usuario y el detalle del total de documentos por cada usuario.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar un diccionario que agrupe la información,

```
data = [["Usuario B"],["Usuario A"], ["Usuario B"], ["Usuario B"],["Usuario A"]] #para emular tu consulta

from collections import defaultdict
def indexOn( data):
    inx= defaultdict(list)
    for t in data:
            inx[t[0]].append(t)
    return inx

sortData = indexOn(data)
```

Esto te da un resultado agrupado de cada elemento

```
>>> defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Usuario A': [['Usuario A'], ['Usuario A']], 'Usuario B': [['Usuario B'], ['Usuario B'], ['Usuario B']]}
```

Solo necesitas recorrerlo y obtener la longitud de cada llave del diccionario

```
for key in sortData: 
    series.append({
        'name': key,
        'data': sortData[key].__len__()
    })
```